# Swift delegates: passing data between view controllers (again)

Tags: swift, delegates, viewcontroller

I’m aware of the reiterative kind of questions about this topic, but I still can’t find a proper answer anywhere.

The view controller that receives data implements the delegate method and sets the delegate to self. The sending view controller fires the method, so the receiver gets the data. So far so good. But when I jump back to my receiving view controller, a new instance of this view controller is created and I’ve lost my data again. How do you avoid this problem?
What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Either (1) don't create a new instance of the view controller, or (2) hand the new instance the existing data after initialization

Comment: Thank you, sounds logical. (I forgot to mention that I'm pretty new to swift.) I'm jumping back to my first view controller by a segue - doesn't this create a new instance anyway? And how would I achieve solution #2? Isn't my instance lost forever?

Comment: Your instance isn't lost forever if you store it (say, in a property). Then you can push or present that view controller instead of using the segue.

Comment: #2… depends on your data. You could add a property to the view controller, and set it in the prepareForSegue method if the data is already available.

Comment: Thank you. I still have to learn a lot..